# How to set a fixed time in JQuery time count down (which doesn't affect when page refreshes)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using [this jquery plugin](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-coming-soon-page-using-html5-and-css3/) for time count down in my web app. Please help me out to remain the count down time not beginning at first each time.I want to set the cont down for a month (30 days 24h 60min 60 sec).So **every time i refresh count down should not be started from the beginning**.Thnx

here is the script code to set the time

```
$('#counter').countdown({
    timestamp : (new Date()).getTime() + 30*24*60*60*1000
});
```

Comment: Create the date object with the time you want, then subtract its values from the hour, minutes, seconds. Notice how you can [construct the date from parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). Create the date you want, create a date from now, subtract the difference -- getTime on that date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today = new Date()
var enddate = new Date(2014,05,01) 


function calcDate(date1,date2) {
   var datadiff = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 1000;

   // calculate (and subtract) whole days
   var days = Math.floor(datadiff / 86400);
   datadiff -= days * 86400;

   // calculate (and subtract) whole hours
   var hours = Math.floor(datadiff / 3600) % 24;
   datadiff -= hours * 3600;

  // calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
  var minutes = Math.floor(datadiff / 60) % 60;
  datadiff -= minutes * 60;

 // what's left is seconds
 var seconds = Math.floor(datadiff % 60);  
 var message = " ";
 message += days + " days " ;
 message += hours + " hours ";
 message += minutes + " minutes \n";
 message += seconds + " seconds \n";
 return message
 }


 a = calcDate(enddate,today);
 alert(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Does everyone need the same end time?  For example, if you want to launch your site on March 5, 2014 at 5 PM Eastern, then you want to set the launch time like so:

```
var ts = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 2, 7, 22))
$('#counter').countdown({
    timestamp : ts
});
```

Alternatively, if each user needs to see a unique countdown, then you want to persist the time in a cookie.  For example, if I open the page 5 minutes after you open the page.  Should the timer be 5 minutes apart?  If yes, then use the cookie.  If no and both of our timers should be the same, then pass to the counter the desired end date.

*Note: UTC is set if timezones matter for you.*

Answer (score 1):

If you need persistence, rather than creating a new date object in javascript, pass the date from the backend which should be saved the first time you start the countdown.

Comment: Good idea, it could be stored in a hidden element and retrieved on refresh, or stored in session on the backend.

Comment: but i can do this only using frontend script,right? Any suggestions

Comment: You can, if you use cookies, or local storage, or something similar.

Comment: Is there any known tutorial , you have done for accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to persist data. One way might to to store the date into a cookie.

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

date = getCookie('date');

if(!date) {
    document.cookie="date=" + new Date().getTime() + 30*24*60*60*1000 + ";";
    date = getCookie('date');
}

alert(date);
```

That should help you persist the date between browser refreshes, but only as long as the cookie lasts.

Comment: Thanks! As you said this only stands as long as the cookie lasts.But thanks for the answer,for telling how to use cookies for this :)